# Hiding a particular row in grid view using different buttons

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How can I hide/display a particular row in grid view using different single toggle button? For example if I click on a button, it will hide the third row of the grid view, and when I click on it again, it will show the row.

[image]

Here is my aspx code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <button id="Button1" type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
         Transcript of Records
    </button>                
    <button id="Button2" type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
         Checklist
    </button>              
    <button id="Button3" type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
          Registration Form
    </button>
    <button id="Button4" type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
           Good Moral
    </button>
    <button id="Button5" type="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
           Honorary Dismissal
    </button>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name of Request" HeaderStyle-Width='100px'/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="TAT" HeaderText="Processing Time" HeaderStyle-Width='100px'/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="QTY" HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderStyle-Width='100px'/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" HeaderStyle-Width='100px'/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" HeaderStyle-Width='100px'/>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>                
</div>
</form>
```

Will this require JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, But first you need to identify which row you wanted to hide.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)    
{    
    Label YourControl= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("YourControl");    
    if (YourControl != null)    
    {    
        if (YourControl.Text.Trim() == "0")    
        {    
            LinkButton YourControl= (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("YourControl");    
            YourControl.Visible = false;    
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You can bind grid-view on each of you button so it will call GridView1_RowDataBound so you can filter you text there.

Comment: sorry im new to this, where did you get the lblBalanceAmount?